# SJSS function to get raw body data

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, json, ssjs, webhooks

I am using a shopify API webhook to post JSON data on an event to a cloud page URL which currently is using a static set json to upsert to a DE but will need to get the raw JSON that is sent from the webhook.

I am unable to find a function for this because it is not post form data, it is raw body data according to recycleb.in when I ran the test. I need to know if the functionality for this exist or not so I can either complete it or look for an alternative solution.

Comment: What SSJS functions have you tried?

Comment: Well I had a look at the request functions or even response functions but there is nothing that relates to what I want, usually in javascript you could do something like "request.body", but that does not exist in ssjs...

Comment: I have yet to figure out a way to do that but I would be very interested in it if there is a way.

Answer (score 3):

A solution for this has been found. You will want to use `Platform.Request.GetPostData()` to retrieve the raw POST body content of incoming request.